# update the unselected records in a table and give them a new id

Tags: sql

I have a table with BatchNbr,serialNbr blah blah.........

```
BatchNbr| serialNbr
----- - | ------
P-27    | 501600
p-27      501601
"         501602
""        501603     
""
""           ""
```

Now I want to select top N records from the table and retain the same batchNbr and for unselected records the batchnbr should update to 'P-27-1'.I was able to select top n records by using

```
select top(@top) BatchNbr,SerialNbr from Table.
```

But i am not getting how to update the BatcNbr for remaining records

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: what is your rdbms? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You need to update your table and set BatchNbr = p-27? in All rows?

Comment: if there are 20 records in a table and if user selects top10 records then i need to update the batchnbr from 11-20 as 'p-27-1'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that serial number is unique.. you can do something like this.

```
UPDATE table
SET BatchNbr = 'P-27-1'
WHERE SerialNbr NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP 10 SerialNbr FROM Customer
)
```

Depending on your RDBMS, you may need to modify the query. But this works in MSSQL.